# LEFT Join SQL takes over 5 minutes and crashes

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

---

I have an agency table, which has a many-to-many relationship with zones, countries, regions, cities, industries, professions, sectors, specialisms and sub_specialisms.

There is also a one-to-many relationship with offices and contacts.

Basically what I wanted to do is create a results table showing particular records from those tables.

I have created indexes on every foreign key in the tables. This is my query:

```
SELECT agencies.agency, 
       agencies.website_url, 
       agencies.status, 
       agencies.SIZE, 
       agencies.id, 
       officedata.id, 
       contactdata.name, 
       contactdata.surname, 
       contactdata.job_title, 
       contactdata.email, 
       contactdata.mobile 
FROM   agencies 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT agencies_industries.agency_id, 
                         agencies_industries.industry_id 
                  FROM   agencies_industries) AS industrydata 
         ON agencies.id = industrydata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT agencies_professions.agency_id, 
                         agencies_professions.profession_id 
                  FROM   agencies_professions) AS professiondata 
         ON agencies.id = professiondata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT agencies_sectors.agency_id, 
                         agencies_sectors.sector_id 
                  FROM   agencies_sectors) AS sectordata 
         ON agencies.id = sectordata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT agencies_seniorities.agency_id, 
                         agencies_seniorities.seniority_id 
                  FROM   agencies_seniorities) AS senioritydata 
         ON agencies.id = senioritydata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT agencies_zones.agency_id, 
                         agencies_zones.zone_id 
                  FROM   agencies_zones) AS zonesdata 
         ON agencies.id = zonesdata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT agencies_countries.agency_id, 
                         agencies_countries.country_id 
                  FROM   agencies_countries) AS countrydata 
         ON agencies.id = countrydata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT agencies_regions.agency_id, 
                         agencies_regions.region_id 
                  FROM   agencies_regions) AS regiondata 
         ON agencies.id = regiondata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT agencies_cities.agency_id, 
                         agencies_cities.city_id 
                  FROM   agencies_cities) AS citydata 
         ON agencies.id = citydata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT agencies_specialisms.agency_id, 
                         agencies_specialisms.specialism_id 
                  FROM   agencies_specialisms) AS specialismdata 
         ON agencies.id = specialismdata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT agencies_sub_specialisms.agency_id, 
                         gencies_sub_specialisms.sub_specialism_id 
                  FROM   agencies_sub_specialisms) AS subdata 
         ON agencies.id = subdata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT offices.id, 
                         offices.agency_id, 
                         offices.hq 
                  FROM   offices 
                  WHERE  offices.hq = "1") AS officedata 
         ON agencies.id = officedata.agency_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT contacts.name, 
                         contacts.surname, 
                         contacts.agency_id, 
                         contacts.job_title, 
                         contacts.email, 
                         contacts.mobile 
                  FROM   contacts) AS contactdata 
         ON agencies.id = contactdata.agency_id
```

When executing it, the site loads and loads and after 5 minutes it crashes. I have no idea why it takes so long. In the processes in phpMyAdmin it says "copying to tmp table". After killing this process the site finishes loading with an error. Sometimes after executing this query whole phpMyAdmin doesn't work.

Do you have any idea how to make it work normal?

### PS

In the database there are only about 20 or less rows in each table. Also when supplying WHERE clause at the end with a dummy data, the query executes in 10 seconds showing no results. When I supply data fitting only one result, it executes in about 20 seconds.

## Update

Ok sorry I accepted the answer too fast because I didn't explain exactly why I need to left join those tables which are not used in my previous example.

The point is I need them to be used too, because all of this is a search system - someone would like to search for an agency where it's zone is Africa - in the results it is not displayed but it needs to be selected.

When I changed my query to this:

```
SELECT agencies.agency
                    ,agencies.website_url
                    ,agencies.STATUS
                    ,agencies.size
                    ,agencies.id
                    ,agencies.status
                    ,OfficeData.id
                    ,ContactData.name
                    ,ContactData.surname
                    ,ContactData.job_title
                    ,ContactData.email
                    ,ContactData.mobile
                    FROM agencies
                    LEFT JOIN offices AS OfficeData ON agencies.id = OfficeData.agency_id
                    AND OfficeData.hq = "1"
                    LEFT JOIN contacts AS ContactData ON agencies.id = ContactData.agency_id
                    LEFT JOIN agencies_professions AS ProfessionData ON agencies.id = ProfessionData.agency_id
                    LEFT JOIN agencies_seniorities AS SeniorityData ON agencies.id = SeniorityData.agency_id
                    LEFT JOIN agencies_sectors AS SectorData ON agencies.id = SectorData.agency_id
                    LEFT JOIN agencies_countries AS CountryData ON agencies.id = CountryData.agency_id
                    LEFT JOIN agencies_regions AS RegionData ON agencies.id = RegionData.agency_id
                    LEFT JOIN agencies_sub_specialisms AS SubData ON agencies.id = SubData.agency_id
                    LEFT JOIN agencies_cities AS CityData ON agencies.id = CityData.agency_id
                    LEFT JOIN agencies_zones AS ZoneData ON agencies.id = ZoneData.agency_id
                    LEFT JOIN agencies_specialisms AS SpecialismData ON agencies.id = SpecialismData.agency_id
                    LEFT JOIN agencies_industries AS IndustryData ON agencies.id = IndustryData.agency_id
```

It still loads till crashing the server.

In the processes it says now "Sending data"

Comment: All those subselects serve no purpose and are confusing the query optimizer. See redfilter's answer.

Comment: If you change the begining of your query to `select count(*) from ...`. What result do you get?

Comment: @Karolis I don't get anything - it loads and loads and loads...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some discussion, I think this might work:

```
SELECT A.agency, A.website_url, A.status, A.size, 
       A.id, O.id, C.name, C.surname, 
       C.job_title, C.email, C.mobile 
  FROM agencies A
  LEFT JOIN offices O                     ON (A.id = O.agency_id)
  LEFT JOIN contacts C                    ON (A.id = C.agency_id)
 WHERE O.hq = '1'
   AND A.id IN (
       SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_industries WHERE <criteria for industries>
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_professions WHERE <criteria for professions>
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_sectors WHERE <criteria for sectors>
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_seniorities WHERE <criteria for seniorities>
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_zones WHERE <criteria for zones>
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_countries WHERE <criteria for countries>
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_regions WHERE <criteria for regions>
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_cities WHERE <criteria for cities>
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_specialisms WHERE <criteria for specialisms>
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_sub_specialisms WHERE <criteria for sub_specialisms>);
```

You will need to replace each of the  with your search criteria.

If you want to plug in criteria dynamically, you can use dummy false conditions OR'd with your plugged in criteria, like this:

```
SELECT A.agency, A.website_url, A.status, A.size, 
       A.id, O.id, C.name, C.surname, 
       C.job_title, C.email, C.mobile 
  FROM agencies A
  LEFT JOIN offices O                     ON (A.id = O.agency_id)
  LEFT JOIN contacts C                    ON (A.id = C.agency_id)
 WHERE O.hq = '1'
   AND A.id IN (
       SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_industries WHERE 0 = 1 OR (<criteria for industries>)
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_professions WHERE 0 = 1 OR (<criteria for professions>)
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_sectors WHERE 0 = 1 OR (<criteria for sectors>)
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_seniorities WHERE 0 = 1 OR (<criteria for seniorities>)
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_zones WHERE 0 = 1 OR (<criteria for zones>)
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_countries WHERE 0 = 1 OR (<criteria for countries>)
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_regions WHERE 0 = 1 OR (<criteria for regions>)
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_cities WHERE 0 = 1 OR (<criteria for cities>)
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_specialisms WHERE 0 = 1 OR (<criteria for specialisms>)
       UNION SELECT agency_id FROM agencies_sub_specialisms WHERE 0 = 1 OR (<criteria for sub_specialisms>));
```

Comment: Your code is technically the same as the one I put in my updated version, it doesn't work... :(

Comment: How much data do you have in each of the tables listed in the query? Also, how are your tables indexed?

Comment: Not more than 20 rows in each table. I just clicked "index" in each foreign key in the tables.

Comment: Ok... I know that you need all these linked tables for your searching, but as a process of limination, what happens if you remove all of them apart from agencies, offices and contacts? Does the query work then? How quick is it?

Comment: Then add them back in, one by one... testing each time. Does one of the tables cause it to fail... or does it gradually get slower and slower with each additional table?

Comment: We finally got to somewhere - when I delete joining the sub_specialisms it loads about 15 seconds, when deleteing sub_specialisms and regions it loads in 1 second. When deleting only regions it takes very long.

EDIT When I delete sub_specialisms AND any other join it loads rapidly. If I delete only sub_specialisms it loads for 10 - 15 secs.

Comment: So I think you might have a problem with sub_specialisms... What do you get if you run: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM agencies_sub_specialisms?

Comment: Your query returns just 4 rown and should around 20

Comment: Ok... make the JOINs back into LEFT JOINs... I made an assumption about your data, which was probably wrong.

Comment: Let me finish all the things in here and once I'm sure your answer will be accepted :)

Comment: Perhaps this would not be the best solution for larger databases, but I liked the universal idea. +1 P.S. I would write `false` instead of `0=1` :)

Comment: Ok this query results in displaying all the agencies even if industry/sector etc. is not matching the one supplied in the WHERE clause. And I need to see only the ones which are actually matching.

Comment: Can you post your new query, including all the extra criteria?

Comment: After selecting a lot of different options: http://wklej.org/id/603155/ At least it works fast. Lol.

Comment: @PiotrChabros Why do you changed this `0 = 1 OR` to this `1 = 1 AND` ? This is the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: After changing to `0 = 1 OR` the result is the same

Comment: @PiotrChabros Nope, not always. When some tables have no criteria then there is a difference.

Comment: Nope. Even if I select only one criteria and the rest is only `0 = 1 OR` I still have displayed all the agencies from the system. Only the last conditions `WHERE agencies.jobs_enabled` etc. work.

Comment: The query in my answer will work for searches that will match this OR this OR this. If you want this AND this AND this, then it's a bit more difficult, and I'll have to think of a different solution. Which type of search do you want? OR or AND?

Comment: Will you be available tomorrow? If you could work with me on this tomorrow I can give you something in return ;) Right now I need to go. You have skype?

Comment: @PiotrChabros Have you changed all `1 = 1` to `0 = 1` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm around tomorrow, but don't have skype.

Comment: Well I can't think of any other way we can communicate so if you could get skype it would be nice.

Comment: Due to your long help I will accept your answer, it helped me figure out where the problem is. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

There are two problems with your query. 1) There are a lot of needless subselects. 2) You are LEFT JOINing on tables you never select data from.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT agencies.agency
    ,agencies.website_url
    ,agencies.STATUS
    ,agencies.size
    ,agencies.id
    ,OfficeData.id
    ,ContactData.NAME
    ,ContactData.surname
    ,ContactData.job_title
    ,ContactData.email
    ,ContactData.mobile
FROM agencies
LEFT JOIN offices AS OfficeData ON agencies.id = OfficeData.agency_id
    AND OfficeData.hq = "1"
LEFT JOIN contacts AS ContactData ON agencies.id = ContactData.agency_id
```

Comment: @Piotr I see you removed the Accept, is there a problem with my answer?

Comment: @RedFilter I've tried to run the sql query by the phpMyAdmin console, and by the query through cakephp framework - it doesn't work either way

Comment: The problem can be that large part of data has the same `agency_id`. Then this query can result in a very large result set. 20^13=81920000000000000

Comment: So what is the solution? There must be a way to solve this problem.

Comment: @PiotrChabros If my assumption was right then you need to reduce your result set with filters. Are you going to show millions of data to the user? You should query only the data that you are going to show for the user, not more.

Comment: @Karolis: I don't think this will produce 20^13 rows... as there is criteria on each join... you'll only get 20^13 rows if there is no criteria. i.e. a cartesian product.

Comment: @BG100 Let's imagine that all `agency_id=1` in all tables :) The problem is that joining condition is not a filter criteria.

Comment: The only data shown as a result is the one selected at the beginning of the query.

Comment: @Piotr how long does my query above take?

Comment: @PiotrChabros Yeah, but there are so many rows. Do you need to show millions of rows?

Comment: @Karolis: If all acency_id = 1, then you'll only get one row returned.

Comment: At the end I just GROUP BY agencies.id so there are no multiplied agencies and no many rows :)

Comment: @Piotr and how long does your query take when you add a WHERE clause for zone = africa?

Comment: It loads for 10 - 15 seconds if I supply data which doesn't fit any result. If I supply data which eventually would return some results, it loads forever.

Comment: @BG100 I don't know what are you talking about :) If you have a table with one row having agency_id=1 and you have another table having 20 rows with agency_id=1 then you'll have at least 20 rows after the join.

Comment: I would have, but the GROUP BY statement groups by a selected value so it's unique and there are no repetitions.

Comment: @PiotrChabros You know I think the problem is that you want to join so much tables at once. You should construct this query dynamically. This means that when someone will need to search for `zone='africa'` then join the table `agencies_zones`, otherwise do not join it. It's a bad practice to join tables that has no criteria.

Comment: @Piotr I agree with Karolis. It is pretty standard to write dynamic SQL for complex search queries. Only join the tables you need for a given search.

Comment: What if someone would select all the criteria? It is possible and the query wouldn't handle it too. But after a research now I have noticed that he query crashes when there is a sub_specialism JOIN. If deleted, it loads in 10 seconds. If I delete any other it doesn't load. What could be wrong about it ?

Comment: @Piotr Check the indexes on that table, and see how many rows are in it.

Comment: @PiotrChabros If someone selects all the criteria then you will have many filters in `where` clause, so then your query will be fast enough even with all those joins. And yes, check the indexes on all your tables.

Comment: @RedFilter 534 rows and indexes are set.